# Is there a way to mark a specific segment of a Microsoft Word document containing scanned images?

Tags: microsoft-word, fax, change-tracking

I have a Word document which mostly amounts to scanned images of a fax (one per page).

By default, I see how to use the "Track Changes" (MS Word 2016 Professional) feature to make a comment on the scanned image for one page. That might get the point across coarsely, but I'd ideally like something more fine-grained.

Is there a way to add a comment to one specific rectangle, or some specific point, within the larger image that constitutes the sole content of a page?

Alternately, can I (e.g.) set the image as a page background, and then add comments to whitespace?

Thanks,

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you simply wanting to write over the top of these scanned images or are you actually just wanting to have a comment against them that is hidden when printing or do you want precise commenting on things?

Answer (score 1):

One trick, though you don't need "track changes" enabled you just need to adjust the image formatting and use normal (blank) text to pin comments to.

For each image you have, change the "wrap text" property for each image to "behind text", you can find this by clicking the image, selecting the new "format" tab in the ribbon and then in the "arrange" properties area.

Then you will be able to insert text whitespace (space characters) on top of your images and then select that whitespace and then on the review tab you can select "new comment".

If you don't need the "comment" then you can just use standard text to write over the image.

It's not a perfect system and may be affected by your print margins if they change, but it looks like it might work.